# Create a Gregorian Calender date with YY, MM, DD, HH, SS and time zone (XXX)

Tags: java, calendar, gregorian-calendar

In my application, I need to create a Gregorian Calender object using the date, time and time zone objects. I happen to have all data in string/int format viz:
DD, MM, YY, HH, SS, XXX .

```
E.g. 20 , 03 , 14 , 09 , 30 , PST
```

Can I create a calender object using all the above parameters ??

I tried using java Calender

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(14 , 02 , 20 , 9 , 30 , 00);
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
```

but it doesn't allow me to use timezone and always picks up my server timezone (EDT). So I always end up with :
Thu Mar 20 09:30:00 **EDT** 2014

What I actually need is :  Thu Mar 20 09:30:00 **PST** 2014

Comment: Try creating using the new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone) constructor and then setting the other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues. First you should use as year 2014, not just 14 as input parameter of `GregorianCalendar`. Then SS probably stands for minutes, not seconds?! Look at this commented code:

```
// don't use the Calendar class, you surely want the gregorian calendar
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 02, 20, 9, 30, 00); // not 14!!!

// getting time zone via zone name PST which is not unique, it could also stand for 
// Pakistan Standard Time, try to use "America/Los_Angeles" (more reliable)
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST");
calendar.setTimeZone(tz);

// output of java.util.Date#toString() depends on local time zone (my case Europe/Berlin => CET)
System.out.println(calendar.getTime()); // Tue Mar 20 18:30:00 CET 14

// PST is 8 hours behind UTC and 9 hours behind CET
System.out.println("PST: " + tz.getRawOffset() / 3600000);

// correct output in PST-zone with your wish format
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

I get as output: Thu Mar 20 09:30:00 PDT 2014

So PDT instead of PST (daylight saving activated at this time point in PST-zone.

```
System.out.println(tz.inDaylightTime(calendar.getTime())); // true
```